# Creating GRID in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo

How do I create a Grid thematic map in MapInfo?

I have 5 different points with different color codes.

I'm using MapInfo 12.

Answer (score 3):

You could try creating a MapInfo Grid (.mig) by creating a grid thematic:

[image]

Then select the grid option on the left at the bottom:

[image]

Pick your table and the field which you want to use as your Z, also the location where you want to save your MIG :

[image]

Play with the colours settings and interpolation method:

[image]